Locus of a point whose distance from two points is fixed (but not necessarily equal) in 3D geometry
Suppose there are two fixed points $S_1$ and $S_2$
Let the moving point be $P$ 
$PS_1$ and $PS_2$ are fixed but not necessarily equal.
Now I think it is a circle. Obtained by rotation of vertex of triangle $(PS_1S_2)$ whose side lengths and base,$(S_1S_2)$ are fixed.
Since the base and dimensions of the triangle are fixed, the mid-point of $S_1S_2$ and its distance from $P$ are fixed so its rotation is a circle, right?

I could neither prove nor visualise this properly
If $PS_1$ and $PS_2$ are fixed, then their sum and difference are also fixed so it could be ellipse or hyperbola

So what kind of curve or solid is this thing?

If $PS_1$ and $PS_2$ are fixed, then there are only two positions available to $P$ (provided $PS_1+PS_2>S_1S_2$). If you mean that the RATIO $PS_1/PS_2$ is fixed, then yes, the locus of $P$ is a circle.

not a curve, but only two points. If distance to $S_1$ is fixed, then $P \in \odot(S_1,S_1P)$ if $S_2$ is fixed, then $P \in \odot(S_2,S_2P)$ the meeting of them are $P$ and the reflection of $P$ wrt to line $S_1S_2$

Sorry about that. I meant in 3D @hellofriends

@Intelligentipauca

@Aurelius two spheres meet at a circle, so your locus is a circle lying on the plane perpendicular to line $S_1S_2$ passing through $P$, whose center $O$ is $S_1S_2 \cap$ the plane and radius is $OP$

Just to give you an answer:
Indeed if $d(P,S_1)$ is constant, then $P$ lies on the spherical surface $\odot(S_1,S_1P)$, on the same manner $P \in \odot (S_2,S_2P)$. Because $P$ is on the meeting of two spheres, $P$ lies on a circle on the plane $\alpha \perp S_1S_2$ whose center is $\alpha \cap S_1S_2$ and the radius is the distance from $P$ to the line $S_1S_2$.

But if the difference and sum of distances are constant it can be hyperbola or ellipse??

nope, the distances themselves won't be equal to the distances $PS_1$ and $PS_2$, think of the analogous in 2-D, it is pretty straight forward.

unless you're talking about a different problem of course

Do the spheres always intersect? For $S_1S_2<PS_1$ and $S_1S_2<PS_2$

spheres with a point in common always intersect, if $P$ is on the line $S_1S_2$, it will be on a single point, if not, it will be in a circle.
